# Is it possible to make and submit a form using jquery/javascript only using `.html` extension for page.?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

Is it necessary to change the extension of page from .html to .php or .aspx to make a working form?

I'm making a single page website. I need to make a form on the page with 3 or 4 field. and the data of form should go to an email address which I will define.

Is it possible to make and submit a form using jquery/javascript only with `.html` page.?

or if it's not possible can I `iframe` a php form in `.html` page, will it work?

Answer (score 1):

You need a serverside scripting language to process the form. Depending on your server, you can add any extension you want to the page and use the servers rewriting engine to internally redirect it to a .php page.

You could also very easily submit the form using ajax to a .php script with no rewriting but without javascript, the form would either fail or the user would see the .php extension.

Comment: Technically you can post the form back with GET to the html page itself and process it within javascript, not really sure how useful it would be though

Answer (score 1):

You are asking whether you need server side code or not (because server side scripts could have any extension, including `html`). The answer is yes, you need the code if you are going to send emails. Iframes are also possible, the form will be embedded into HTML page via Iframe.

If all you want to do is to have `html` extension for the page, you should use Rewrite capabilities of your web-server, not Iframes.

Also, from [this page](http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/dynamicstatic.shtml):

> If your intention is to have your
>   whole site appear as static HTML pages
>   while in reality being generated by
>   (say) PHP, instead of only isolated
>   pages as is assumed above, a simpler
>   method than that outlined above is to
>   simply add the following line to your
>   .htaccess file:
>
> ```
> AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any server side scripting language then you will not be able to send mail automatically. To send mail you need mail server.

but if you want to give the user the ability to send the mail themselves, then you can use "`mailto:`" feature. using mail to you can pop up that users outlook or even you can use GMAIL also.

but here, responsibility is user's. If user doesn't want to send the mail then he/she can.

```
<form action="mailto:you@youraddress.com" enctype="text/plain" 
method="POST" onsubmit="sendMail(this);return false;">
<select name="selOne">
<option value="Dog">Dog</option>
<option value="Cat">Cat</option>
</select>
<textarea name="txtOne"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function sendMail(_frm) {
    var eml = "you@youraddress.com";
    var bod = "&body=" + _frm.selOne.value + " ¦¦ " + _frm.txtOne.value;
    var subj = "?subject=Whatever you want";
    location.href = "mailto:" + eml + subj + bod;
}
</script>
```

for detail you can google about "mailto using JavaScript".
If you are using any server side language then the case is different.